# Sharepoint field form size changed

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, list-form, powerapps-forms

Yesterday I tried to make changes to a form of our company and now I see it as if it were in full screen. How can I bring it back to its original vertical size?

From this:
[image]

To this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to List Settings, click on the List Settings, then Advanced Settings as shown in the picture below:[image: x]

Then find **Dialog** section and select *No*:

[image]

Do not forget to save it.

Answer (score 0):

The list form displayed in screen one looks like powerapps list form and you wish to change it to default SharePoint vertical form.

1. goto List Settings.
2. Select "form setting" under the general settings column.
3. select "Use the default Sharepoint Form" option and Click OK.

Hope this solution will work for you.

[image]